# JPA condition or (Expression and Expression)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have a problem with my JPA query.

In fact, I want to have a SQL query like this :

```
OR( 
   foo = true AND foo1 = true
),
OR( 
   foo1=true AND foo2=true AND foo3=true
)
```

This is my JPA query :

```
predicates.add(
            criteriaBuilder.or(
                    criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("foo"),true),
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(join1.get("foo"),true)
                                ),
                        criteriaBuilder.and(
                                criteriaBuilder.equal(join2.get("foo"),true),
                                criteriaBuilder.equal(join21.get("foo"),true),
                                criteriaBuilder.equal(join22.get("foo"),true)
                                )
                        )
                );
```

But I have :

```
OR foo = true 
AND foo1 = true
OR foo1=true 
AND foo2=true 
AND foo3=true
```

Comment: Not sure I understood what you are after.  Or(),Or() doesn't make sense to me, and what you have put into Criteria API is the equivalent of "( foo = true AND foo1 = true ) OR ( foo1=true AND foo2=true AND foo3=true )"  in JPQL or SQL.

Comment: you mean to say in your question that you are looking for *"(foo = true AND foo1 = true) OR (foo1=true AND foo2=true AND foo3=true)"* ? And your JPA implementation isn't putting the braces in? I know the one I use (DataNucleus) includes braces for AND/OR separation. Raise a bug on your JPA implementation if that is the case